# setTimeout animation is not consistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

How can i convert my animation into requestAnimationframe. I am using setTimeout to perform animation and it is having problem in different browsers. The animation works fine in chrome and safare but in firefox and IE the animation is working differently. This is my [Jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/t1qjzfuf/).

```
setTimeout(function() {$('.sub-copy').fadeIn(1000);}, 6300);
setTimeout(function() {$('#girl-arm').hide(500);}, 2000);
setTimeout(function() {$('#dis').fadeIn(1000);},6300);
setTimeout(function() {$('#desk-car').hide();},1);
setTimeout(function() {$('#desk-car').fadeIn(1000);}, 3000);
setTimeout(function() {$('#desk-car').fadeOut(1000);}, 6000);
setTimeout(function() {$('#wheel-l').fadeIn(1000);}, 3300);
setTimeout(function() {$('#wheel-r').fadeIn(1000);}, 3300);
setTimeout(function() {$('#girl-1').fadeIn(200);}, 300);
setTimeout(function() {$('#window-l').fadeIn(200);}, 300);
setTimeout(function() {$('#window-r').fadeIn(200);}, 300);
setTimeout(function() {$('#window-l').fadeOut(1000);}, 6000)
setTimeout(function() {$('#window-r').fadeOut(1000);}, 6000)
setTimeout(function() {$('#clock-lamp').fadeIn(200);},300);
setTimeout(function() {$('#girl-1').fadeOut(500);},2800);
setTimeout(function() {$('#clock-lamp').fadeOut(500);},2800);
//setTimeout(function() {$('#clock2').fadeIn(500);},2500);
setTimeout(function(){$("#clock2").fadeIn(function(){
  $(this).animate({'left': '-=110px'},3000);
});},3000);
setTimeout(function() {$('#clock2').fadeOut(200);},6000);
setTimeout(function() {$('.sub-copy').fadeOut(500);}, 10000);
setTimeout(function() {$('#dis').fadeOut(500);}, 10000);
}
```

I want to convert this into requestAnimationFrame. I am new to javascript and read that setTimeout is not an idea for multiple animations. As in my case it is working differently in firefox and IE where wheels are spinning after the car is disappeared.

Or is there any better way to perform this animation please suggest me any better way which should be consistent in all browsers. Help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance

Comment: Relying on `setTimeout` calls to remain synchronised is asking for a world of pain. I would look in to using keyframes

Comment: can you tell me in detail please how can i use this in my case. I am a beginner in JS sorry about that

Comment: perhaps [this](https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes)

Comment: @OwaisAhmed I was referring to CSS keyframes, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) for more information

Comment: you can do this easily with css, see comment above for documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear: `requestAnimationFrame` is a feature to build unitary animations, like your fadeIn / fadeOut / hide / animate from jQuery. You would not use it to trigger different scenes in your video, like you are doing in your example with `setTimeout`.

Many libraries build on requestAnimationFrame (and other fallback methods when appropriate) to replace the jQuery transitions. They can also build more complex scenes, which can be of interest to you. Check out [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/) examples on their homepage. This type of alternative should provide you with a much more robust technology to build advertising(-like) videos.

As pointed out in the question comments, you could also give a shot at CSS animations, but this could become quite complex for an entire video, whereas JavaScript (possibly through libraries like the one mentioned above) gives a lot of control easily.

To come back to your original question, and ignoring the possibility to switch to another technology, there is a high chance that your different scenes become out-of-sync because all are defined from the same initial time origin (the moment your `setTimeout`'s are executed). The `setTimeout` function does not guarantee that your callback function will be executed *exactly* after the specified amount of time: it will be just **queued** at that moment, and it will have to wait for the JavaScript thread to become available before starting. So if the CPU is in the middle of many animations, your callback may have to wait quite some time before starting, and then you lose synchronization. Furthermore you would get different results depending on the client browser, CPU, but also current CPU load!

To overcome this, you could simply split your "video" in its individual scenes, and define new timeouts for the next scene only at the end of the current scene, i.e. nested in the callback function of the previous timeout. That way, even if the current scene takes a lot of CPU, it will last a little bit longer than expected, and it will just delay the next scenes, instead of completing while the next scene has already begun (if it had a chance to).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t1qjzfuf/1/